# How to share an instance across several php files a-la-Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

Greetings Everyone,

I'm currently using Wordpress as my CMS and leveraging Facebook's Graph API for the user account/registration "stuff".

My question is how do I use Facebook's PHP SDK (found here: http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/), when Wordpress compiles several php files to output a single webpage? In other words, Wordpress' templates **header.php** + **index.php** + **footer.php** = what you see on www.example.com

If I create my instance of the Facebook Application in **HEADER.PHP**, how will I make references to them in **INDEX.PHP** and **FOOTER.PHP**?

Thanks in advance!

----- SAMPLE CODE ---

**in header.php**

```
<?php
require '/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => 'xxx',
  'secret' => 'xxx',
  'cookie' => true,
));
?>
```

**in index.php**

```
<?php
$session = $facebook->getSession();
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set `$facebook` in `header.php`, you **won't** be able to access it in `index.php` unless you globalise it.

This is because `header.php` is loaded in via the function `get_header()`, which narrows [the scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) of all non-global variables.

So you could either globalise `$facebook` **OR**, since you want a single instance of `Facebook`, I'd strongly recommend using a [singleton helper function](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/singleton.html#helper.function);

```
function get_facebook_instance()
{
    static $f;
    if (!isset($f)) {
        if (!class_exists('Facebook'))
            require('/facebook.php');
        $f = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => 'xxx',
            'secret' => 'xxx',
            'cookie' => true,
        ));
    }
    return $f;
}
```

Note: If you're using PHP5, you don't have to worry about returning by reference.

Comment: Thank you @TheDeadMedic. You're right on. I placed the instance helper function inside functions.php and can now access the variables.

Comment: Nice answer @TheDeadMedic and great link to boot :)

Comment: This answer looks like exactly what I need. I'm still a little curious about how to access the SDK from the template files. Is it using $facebook or $f? DO I have to call get_facebook_instance() in every template file first, or just once in functions? Do I need to call get_facebook_instance from an add_action hook?

Comment: `get_facebook_instance()` simply returns a static instance of the SDK class. Just assign it to a variable at the start of each template file where you need it (`$whatever = get_facebook_instance()`), then use `$whatever->sdk_method()`.

Answer (score 1):

Once you include the facebook client in your header.php file and create an instance of that:

```
$facebook = new Facebook('API', 'SECRET');
```

You can then access the facebook client instance `$facebook` from your index.php file or even footer.php file or anyother file on which header.php is included.

Comment: You sure? This is what I get after initiating in header and then having stuff call in index.php

Fatal error: Call to a member function getSession() on a non-object in

Comment: @st4ck0v3rfl0w:You should also post your sample code to see how you are actually doing it. It could help us further.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is processed in order, that is you need to make sure that `header.php` is included before the call happens in `index.php`. It's possible that overall you have something like this:

In index.php

```
<?php
// blah blah other code
$session = $facebook->getSession();
// blah blah more code
include('header.php');
```

Which of course would be read as:

```
<?php
// blah blah other code
$session = $facebook->getSession();
// blah blah more code
require '/facebook.php';
// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => 'xxx',
  'secret' => 'xxx',
  'cookie' => true,
));
```

You can see when you look at the overall code that `$facebook` wouldn't exist yet.

Add a `var_dump($facebook);` to the end of header.php (after you have set `$facebook` and also one to the start of index.php (right before you try to use `$facebook`).

The other thing that it might be is that you call to the `Facebook` Graph API isn't working correctly and is returning false or something. Your `var_dump` output will be the same if `$facebook` exists and is hasn't connected properly (or something like that), but will be different if you try to access `$facebook` before you have set it (one will be `NULL` and will generate an [`E_NOTICE`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php), the other will be a Facebook object - or whatever is returned from the Facebook Graph API call).

Comment: Actually....I just performed vardump in header.php when I created the $facebook instance in index.php and it returned NULL. I also did it the other way around and performed vardump in index.php when I created the instance in header.php and it also returned NULL.....

WHAT'S GOING ON!?

Comment: `var_dump($facebook)` returns `null` or `var_dump($facebook->getSession())` returns `null`? If it's the former, then you aren't connecting to Facebook properly, if it's the latter, it's because you don't have a Facebook session, make sure you have a "Connect to Facebook" button or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the Wordpress Facebook Connect Plugin, which already implements this.